# How to include 3rd party aar into Android React Native module?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I am building an android React Native module and my code imports classes from a 3rd party SDK which is provided as an aar file. How should I bundle this file into my module? I tried adding

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs: 'libs'
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    ... other deps ...
    compile (name:'my-external-lib', ext:'aar')
}
```

to the build.gradle file and putting this my-external-lib.aar file into `libs/` folder, but still getting an error when building MyApp react-native application with react-native-my-module included:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 
':app:_developmentDebugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find :my-external-lib:.
     Required by:
         MyApp:app:unspecified > MyApp:react-native-my-module:unspecified
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I managed to solve this question by myself.
It seems that you need to define `repositories` in the main project to allow sub-projects locate their dependencies.

Putting this to the main project build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs: 'libs'
    }
}
```

did the trick.

I believe though, that this is not the correct way to include sub-projects with dependencies, because you're obviously can't know how to amend your build.gradle file if this library is a 3rd party lib from npm.
So, can someone explain why this worked and how should it be done in the right way?

Comment: Hey I followed exactly but still I am getting Project with path `xxxx could not found in project yyyyy`. If possible can you share the structure of your module?

Answer (score 2):

In your module's `android/build.gradle` file, you'll want to add the `.aar` as an artifact.

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file("NAME_OF_YOUR_FILE.aar"))
```

Comment: in which section of the build.gradle does this goes into? or just at the end of the file?

Comment: @gtfargo I've tried this but the classes from the aar are not resolved. How did you make it work?

Answer (score 2):

What ever you have written is absolutely correct but you just written in wrong place
you have written the code in the build.gradle(Project:project_name)
you just have to write the code in build.gradle(Module:app) file and the .arr file has to be paste in the projects lib folder

i.e. 
repositories {
     flatDir {
          dirs 'libs'
     }
}

dependencies {
      ... other deps ...
      compile (name:'my-external-lib', ext:'aar')
}

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.gradle you should include this lib e.g:

```
include ':app',  ':my-external-lib'
```

And you can compile it as a normal project e.g: `compile project(':my-external-lib')`

Also your `my-external-lib` build.gradle should be like :

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('my-external-lib.aar'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I successfully included a 3rd party `.aar` file into android react native module.

Please look at my answer to this question: [How to include AAR in React Native Android build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859114/how-to-include-aar-in-react-native-android-build/60399937#60399937)

Answer (score 0):

after trying so Long I finally got it
there how you should do it :

1. Add

   repositories {
         flatDir {
          dirs 'libs'
         }
   }

into project:grindle (not module.grindle)
and

2. Add dependies into app:grindle (not module.grindle)

Answer (score 0):

I you are trying to use third party software in react-native module than

1. Add aar file in reactnativeModule/android/libs
2. Add

   allprojects {
   repositories {
   flatDir {
   dirs: 'libs'
   }
   }
   }
   in build.gradle of reactnativeModule/android/build.grindle
3. add dependencies just in
   `dependencies { implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:${safeExtGet('reactnativeVersion', '+')}" of reactnativeModule/android/build.grindle`